# Send string over Android app to java Server

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I'm using this code. Server and android app.

https://github.com/luugiathuy/Remote-Bluetooth-Android

I can send int commands but I want to send strings for more information

I create the issue in the repository but I want all the help posible

In the server I have this

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        try {

            // prepare to receive data
            InputStream inputStream = mConnection.openInputStream();

            System.out.println("waiting for input");

            while (true) {
                int command = inputStream.read();

                StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
                IOUtils.copy(inputStream, writer, Charsets.UTF_8);
                String theString = writer.toString();
                System.out.println(theString);

                if (command == EXIT_CMD)
                {   
                    System.out.println("finish process");
                    break;
                }

                processCommand(command);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

with this response...

```
BlueCove version 2.1.1-SNAPSHOT on winsock
04c6093b00001000800000805f9b34fb
waiting for connection...
waiting for connection...
waiting for input
23456789?

finish process
```

BUT in Android I send "123456789" with this code

```
public void write(String out) {
        // Create temporary object
        ConnectedThread r;
        // Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread
        synchronized (this) {
            if (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) return;
            r = mConnectedThread;
        }
        // Perform the write unsynchronized
        r.write(out.getBytes());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Few edits...

I comment this line

```
int command = inputStream.read();
```

and I get the "full" string this this code

```
BufferedReader bReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
String line = "";
while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) 
{
     System.out.println(line);
}
```

123456789**ÿ**

I can eliminate the last char but is not the best...

In my android app I have this

```
mCommandService.write(editText.getText().toString().trim());
editText.getText().clear();
mCommandService.stop();
```

If I remove the last line, the ÿ disapear. So I guess that is the stop command. Can I remove that or is native?

Comment: You read in some termination character as UTF-8. That is why you see ÿ